# Query how attendees have said they will attend to a calendar invite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Last year Google Calendar added the ability for guests to indicate whether they will be attending a meeting "in a meeting room" or "remotely" ([source](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)).

I'd like to get this info from the Calendar AppScript API, but it seems the [GuestStatus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status) enum doesn't provide this info.

Does anyone know hot to programmatically get info on whether guests have RSVP'd saying they will be remote or in the office?

Comment: This feature is not supported by the api.  submit a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B

Comment: Thanks, done!  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233703122